# How to include the post title in the post content in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

If the post title is "concepts"
I want the post content to be something like that
"in "post title" we care about our client satisfaction by following "post title" high quality policy"
so i want the post content include "concepts" and replace it with post title
I think wordpress shortcode api can do something like that. But i don't know how ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your statement. But I think wordpress hooks can help you do that
You can try someting like:

```
function change_post_title ( $post_title ) {
   if ( $post_title ==  'conecpts'  ) {
     $title = 'The new title'; 
     return $title; 
 }
 return $post_title;
}

add_filter('the_title', 'change_post_title');
```

This will change the post title to "The new post title" if the title is "concepts"

Please make your question clear as to what is the problem and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In your post content you will need add a shortcode where you want the title printed, int eh shortcode example below you will use `[post_title]`.

```
function post_title_shortcode( $atts ){
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID()
        ), $atts ) );

     return get_the_title( $post_id );
}
add_shortcode( 'post_title', 'post_title_shortcode' );
```

With that shortcode you can pass the post id so that if you want to get the title of another post you could do use the shortcode `[bartag post_id="123"]` where 123 is the post id of the title you want to show.

Comment: What if i want to pass the current post title in post content
(I mean without using atts). So the shortcode become more generic and can be used on any post